# UML to HUTN (Human-Usable Textual Notation)

Tags: transformation, dsl, model-driven, epsilon, model-driven-development

The epsilon project (based on eclipse) promises [here](http://www.eclipse.org/epsilon/doc/articles/hutn-basic/) to transform XMI to HUTN. I can't find any documentation for this purpose. Is it too trivial? I don't get it

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you reference has all the information. However, for this to work you need to have an Eclipse IDE with Epsilon installed. (You can get an Epsilon-ready Eclipse from the Epsilon website [here](https://www.eclipse.org/epsilon/download/).)

Then, as instructed in the page you can craete a HUTN model using the HUTN editor. Once you have your model, follow the instructions at the bottom of the page to generate the respective XMI version. Note that it is possible that the extension of the generated model is `.model`, but nonetheless its contents are in the XMI format and can be used anywhere an XMI model is expected.